# Probability of drawing identical cards?

Tags: probability

What's the probability of drawing two identical cards from a pack of $52$ cards with replacement? I know the answer which is $1/52$ I just don't understand why is it $1/52$ and not $1/52\cdot 1/52$.

Please help

Comment: Hello! Just a few things: (1) This isn’t a homework-solving engine, so you need to show your own efforts. That means that the most efficient way to get an answer to your homework is to start with research! This problem is plastered all over the internet. (2) You have to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). (3) We try to keep this site as prestigious and formal as possible. Whininess like the last line of your question is the opposite of that. $\ddot\smile$

Comment: The only whininess I see here is this comment.

Answer (score 4):

The probability you're asking for is the probability that the second draw matches the first draw. That's $\frac{1}{52}$. The value $\frac1{52}\cdot\frac1{52}$ is the probability that both draws are the King of Hearts (or whatever your favorite card may be).

Comment: or even drawing the same random card 3 times.

Answer (score 1):

The first card is random there is a probability of 1 for that!!

Comment: sure there is, there was 100% probability given that you were going to pick two cards that you'd draw 1 card.

Comment: OK, it is 1 agreed!!

Answer (score 1):

How many ways are there to choose two cards from a pack of $52$ cards, with replacement? There are $52\cdot52 = 52^2$ ways.

How many ways are there to have two drawn identical cards in the scenario above? There are $52$ ways - one for each distinct card.

Thus the probability is
$$
\frac{52}{52^2}=\frac{1}{52}.
$$

The ratio
$$
\frac{1}{52^2}
$$
represents the probability of drawing a specific card, say the ace of diamonds, twice. It's not the probability of drawing the same card twice.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to think about it ( kind of given in the comment I made on another answer and in a few other answers). What's the probability that the first card matches the first card ? It's 100% or 1. What's the probability that the second matches the first card $1\over 52$. Since, picking the first card and picking the second card are independent events, we multiply the probabilities, but 1x = x, so the answer ends up being $1\over 52$